# Three.JS - Get list of all objects in last render call

Tags: three.js

Does anyone know how to get a list of all meshes that were rendered in the last render call ?

Comment: Put some code so one can understand the problem

Comment: This is quite simple: 

[http://jsfiddle.net/karimbeyrouti/2d1obmng/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/karimbeyrouti/2d1obmng/4/)

I am looking to get a list of all meshes that have been rendered ( and not frustum culled ) .

Comment: have you found out how to do that?